# Array of images loops itself in each item in my array list of object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please help me out
I am fetching image from a JSON API to my android app for each item in my arraylist. The images are fetching correctly, but instead of setting only the image that is meant for each list item, it is looping and interchanging all the images in all the list on one item and all the list items respectively, thereby making the image in each list item to be changing to different images in seconds.

See the JSON file

```
{  "data":[  
  {  
     "sno":1,
     "id":"3",
     "title":"This Is Great Again",
     "desc":"The details of how a UUID is generated are determined by the device manufacturer and are specific to the device's platform or model.The details of...",
     "free":"Yes",
     "image":"http:\/\/app-web.moneyacademy.ng\/uploads\/145277f3d0499ee8e0dafbac384ca9b4.jpg",
     "date_added":"2017-10-12 10:26PM",
     "no_comment":3,
     "comments":[  ]
  },
  {  
     "sno":2,
     "id":"6",
     "title":"Money Makes The World Go Round",
     "desc":"On this realm, nothing works without money. You need to get some of it or else you'll be grounded.",
     "free":"Yes",
     "image":"http:\/\/app-web.moneyacademy.ng\/uploads\/546a4c29a94f3d70ae9a075ce8afcc6b.jpg",
     "date_added":"2018-02-18 10:06AM",
     "no_comment":0,
     "comments":[  ]
  },
  {  
     "sno":3,
     "id":"7",
     "title":"No One Is Destined To Be Poor",
     "desc":"You will not be poor.",
     "free":"Yes",
     "image":"http:\/\/app-web.moneyacademy.ng\/uploads\/8f19b9cebd1ca4dec74fafcfe23ae0f0.jpg",
     "date_added":"2018-02-18 01:03PM",
     "no_comment":0,
     "comments":[  ]
  },
  {  
     "sno":4,
     "id":"8",
     "title":"What Is Your Money?",
     "desc":"Understand the true definition of your money.",
     "free":"Yes",
     "image":"http:\/\/app-web.moneyacademy.ng\/uploads\/49b35ffb5cabcb7e01dab2d452ec6025.jpg",
     "date_added":"2018-02-18 01:30PM",
     "no_comment":0,
     "comments":[  ]
  },
```

Here is my code for fetching each item and the image

```
private static ArrayList<nauget> extractFeatureFromJson(String freeNaugetJson) {
    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(freeNaugetJson)) {
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList<nauget> naugets = new ArrayList<nauget>();

    try {

        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(freeNaugetJson);
        JSONArray dataArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");

        // If there are results in the data array
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++){

            String title = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            String body = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("desc");
            String totalComments = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("no_comment");
            String image = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image");
            int id = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");

            ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

            //fetch each comment detail
            if (Integer.parseInt(totalComments) > 0) {
                JSONArray commentArray = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("comments");

                for (int j = 0; j < commentArray.length(); j++) {
                    String userName = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("userName");
                    String comment_image = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("userPhoto");
                    String comment = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("comment");
                    String date = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_commented");

                    comments.add(new Comment(userName, comment_image, comment, date));
                }
            }

            // Create a new nauget object
            naugets.add(new nauget(title, body, image, totalComments, comments, id));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the nauget JSON results", e);
    }

    return naugets;
}
```

Here is my custom adapter code where am setting the image and its text data for each list item.

```
 public class NaugetAddapter extends ArrayAdapter<nauget> {

    ArrayList<nauget> naugets;
    private nauget currentNauget;
    private ImageView naugetImage;

    private TextView naugetTitle;
    private TextView naugetBody;
    private TextView commentCount;

    public NaugetAddapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<nauget> naugets) {
        super(context, 0, naugets);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //check if the convert view is null and inflate the view
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.free_nauget_item, parent, false);
        }

        currentNauget = (nauget) getItem(position);

        //find the nauget title textView and set the text
        naugetTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nauget_title);
        naugetTitle.setText(currentNauget.getNauget_title());

        //find the nauget body textView and set the text
        naugetBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nauget_body);
        naugetBody.setText(currentNauget.getNauget_body());

        //set the nauget total comment count
        commentCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
        commentCount.setText(currentNauget.getNaugetTotalComments());

        //set the comment text
        TextView commentText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        commentText.setText(currentNauget.getNaugetCommentText());

        //set the nauget image
        naugetImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nauget_image);
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(currentNauget.getImageUrl());

        //set the share icon
        ImageView shareIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.share_icon);
        shareIcon.setImageResource(currentNauget.getNaugetShareIcon());

        //set share functionality on the share icon
        shareIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My App");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        naugetTitle.getText()
                        + "\n" + naugetBody.getText()
                        + "\n" + naugetImage.getDrawable());
                startActivity(getContext(), Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"), null);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
//            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap image = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
//            mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            naugetImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                ArrayList<nauget> filteredResults = new ArrayList<>();

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            }
        };
    }

    void setFilter(ArrayList<nauget> listItem){
        naugets = new ArrayList();
        naugets.addAll(listItem);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue! you are trying everything fine but you have the **comment ArrayList inside of a loop getting instantiated each time** newly just put it before the outer loop as I did here and the error should go!  **TRY IT**

```
   try {

        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(freeNaugetJson);
        JSONArray dataArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
        //put it here so you won't get a new array for each comment in the loop
        **ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();**
        // If there are results in the data array
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++){

            String title = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            String body = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("desc");
            String totalComments = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("no_comment");
            String image = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("image");
            int id = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
//here after every comment check its making a new comment ArrayList for each comment and filling it out so this can be the cause of the bug! bcz its in the loop
// ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();


            //fetch each comment detail
            if (Integer.parseInt(totalComments) > 0) {
                JSONArray commentArray = dataArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("comments");

                for (int j = 0; j < commentArray.length(); j++) {
                    String userName = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("userName");
                    String comment_image = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("userPhoto");
                    String comment = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("comment");
                    String date = commentArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("date_commented");

                    comments.add(new Comment(userName, comment_image, comment, date));
                }
            }

            // Create a new nauget object
            naugets.add(new nauget(title, body, image, totalComments, comments, id));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the nauget JSON results", e);
    }

    return naugets;
```